# how to disable a button which acts as a link django

Tags: python, html, django, button, hyperlink

What is the best way to disable the "deny" button when "approve" button is clicked ? I have {{some}} that stores the value of approve or deny value.

```
<a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='a' %}"><button>Approve</button></a> 
<a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='d' %}"><button>Deny</button></a>
```

html file

```
{% if some %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
     <tr align="center">
     <th> Student ID </th>
     <th> Student Name </th>
     <th> Start Date </th>
     <th> End Date </th>
     <th> Action </th>
     <th> Status </th>
     </tr>
     {% for item in query_results %}
         <tr align="center">
             <td> {{item.studentID}} </td>
             <td> {{item.studentName}} </td>
             <td> {{item.startDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
             <td> {{item.endDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
             <td><a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='a' %}"><button>Approve</button></a> <a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='d' %}"><button {% if some == 'approve' %} disabled{% endif %}>Deny</button></a></td>
             <td> 
                 {% if item.status %}
                     {{item.status}}
                 {% else %}
                      Pending
                 {% endif %}       
             </td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
       </table>
{% else %}
```

the {{some}} gets from here

views.py

```
def superltimesheet(request):
    query_results = Timesheet.objects.all()
    data={'query_results':query_results, 'some':'some'}
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/supervisor_list_timesheet.html', data)
```

Comment: This is more of a front-end question rather than back-end (Django)

Comment: django doesnt have the functionality to dsiable a button ?

Comment: Django is a server-side framework. As such it offers you to add the `disabled` attribute to buttons on the server based on conditions, as Paulo shows you below. But Django has no functionality for the front-end, read JavaScript or CSS. You'd usually use a JavaScript library for that. That said, you can reload the page on button click or forward to a different page. In this case the you can set the button to disabled on the server. If, however, you wanted immediate response in the browser without reloading the page, you should look into JavaScript, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about what are you asking, but you can do an if statement like

```
{% if some == 'approve' %}
    <a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='d' %}"><button>Deny</button></a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'hrfinance:edit' id=item.id status='a'%}"><button>Approve</button></a>
{% endif %}
```

or:

```
{% if some == 'approve' %}
    <button>Deny</button>
{% else %}
```

tell me if that works or I misunderstood

Comment: I don't think hiding the button entirely is what the OP meant by "disabling".

Comment: this wont work, because we have the {% if some %} before whatever html table. and the {{some}} gets the value from status. Status is the next tuple after the button. If u still rmb how we discussed that in Hangout

Comment: i might as well post my template

Comment: @Nobody please edit the question so that it becomes more clear what you have, what you want and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [`if` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
<button{% if some == 'deny' %} disabled{% endif %}>Approve</button>
```